# Multiple data (text and images upload) with Next Js app router, react hook forms, react dropzone and route handler

Tags: next.js, routes, strapi

In my Next 13 web app, I want authenticated users to be able to upload product data which includes a set of strings, number, a single featured image and an array of product images. The form is a client component which uses the `use client` direction.
Since I can use the form submission in a server component, I had to do it this way form data from **client component -> route handler (so I can get to use cookies in the request) -> Strapi upload api and products api**

1. I have been able to successfully get the images from the react dropzone and set them to an uploadedImage state.
2. I have been able to add the images to the react hook forms data in the submit handler like this:

```
    const fd = new FormData();

    const { featuredImage, images, ...rest } = formData;

    Object.entries(rest).forEach(([key, value]) => {
      fd.append(key, value);
    });

    if (featuredImage) {
      const featuredImageData = images[featuredImage];
      fd.append("featuredImage", featuredImageData);
    }

    images.forEach((image) => {
      fd.append("images", image);
    });

    const response = await fetch("/api/createProduct", {
      method: "POST",
      body: fd,
    });

    const data = await response.json();
  };
```

Now, at the route handler in the `/api/createProduct/route.js` file, I am attempting to get the formData like this:

```
export async function POST(request) {
const formData = await request.formData()

console.log('ROUTE formData', formData);

return Response.json({ status: 'done' })
  }
```

When I console.log the formData, all I get is:

```
ROUTE formData FormData {
  [Symbol(state)]: [
    { name: 'title', value: 'Bakabaka' },
    { name: 'price', value: '124' },
    { name: 'category', value: '1876' },
    { name: 'brand', value: '227' },
    { name: 'images', value: [File] },
    { name: 'images', value: [File] },
    { name: 'images', value: [File] },
    { name: 'images', value: [File] }
  ]
```

I dont know how to get the data in a form Strapi understands. I have searched everywhere online but all the solutions didn't work. Does anyone have any resource that can me with a step by step approach, clearly outlined?

Answer (score 0):

To get a single value from FormData

```
const title = formData.get("title")
```

To get multiple values at once, ex. get multiple files from FormData

```
const images = forumData.getAll("images")
```